# jQuery setInterval() auto refresh div element per 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to refresh left div every 5 seconds. The whole project is to use $.ajax to get JSON data and then to show 4 random elements in the left. The left div block did refresh, but the content didn't change. Always the same images.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du4ly.jpg)

I tried to console.log random index, which did be different every 5s. Why the new created html elements are still the same, though random index is already changed???
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDsMj.png)

```
setInterval(getRandomEles, 5000);

function getRandomEles() {

  if ($('#left').children().length < 4) {

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var idx = Math.floor((Math.random() * arrayImg.length));
      randomArrayImg.push(arrayImg[idx]);
    }

    var leftHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      leftHtml += '<div class="card gallery-map"><img class="card-img-top flex-gallery" src="' + randomArrayImg[i]['image_url'] +
        '" alt=" "><div class="card-body"><p class="card-text">' + randomArrayImg[i]['artiste'] + '</p></div></div>';
    }

    var leftDom = $('#left').append(leftHtml);

  } else {
    $('#left').children().remove();
  }
}
```

HTML is as following:

```
    <main>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hello, Yan, I know the situation but what is the problem?

Comment: I added it. tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you keep pushing `arrayImg[idx]` into `randomArrayImg`
but you did not clear `randomArrayImg` after it refresh so the

```
randomArrayImg[0]
randomArrayImg[1]
randomArrayImg[2]
randomArrayImg[3]
```

are remain unchanged

I don't know how did you declare `randomArrayImg`, so it is a generic way to remove all items inside the array

```
else {
    $('#left').children().remove();
    while(randomArrayImg.length > 0) { //add this
        randomArrayImg.pop();          //add this
    }                                  //add this
}
```

or you can use your own method to clear it smarter